# Модификаторы доступа к полям абстрактного класса

Tags: java, классы

Начал изучать абстрактные класса в java.

Появился такой вопрос:

При апкасте класса Gamepad до Controller я могу достучаться до поля message, хотя не должен. Нужно, чтобы экземпляр message я мог брать только через getControllerMessage.

Сейчас могу сделать так:

```
    Controller controller = new Gamepad();
    controller.message
```

А нужно, чтобы экземпляр можно было взять только через getControllerMessage:

```
    Controller controller = new Gamepad();
    controller.getControllerMessage();
```

А к message я обратиться вообще не мог. Как это реализовать?

Как сделать так, чтобы ControllerMessage message был виден только в объектах, которые наследуют класс Controller и никак иначе?

Или я делаю что-то неправильно?

Помогите, пожалуйста. Только начал :)

Controller.java:

```
public abstract class Controller {

    protected ControllerMessage message;

    public abstract ControllerMessage getControllerMessage();

    public abstract float getMinThrottle();
    public abstract float getMaxThrottle();
    public abstract float getMinSteering();
    public abstract float getMaxSteering();
}
```

ControllerMessage.java:

```
public class ControllerMessage {
    private float throttle;
    private float steering;

    public float getThrottle() {
        return throttle;
    }

    public void setThrottle(float throttle) {
        this.throttle = throttle;
    }

    public float getSteering() {
        return steering;
    }

    public void setSteering(float steering) {
        this.steering = steering;
    }

    public boolean getIsReverse() {
        return isReverse;
    }

    public void setReverse(boolean reverse) {
        isReverse = reverse;
    }

    private boolean isReverse;
}
```

Gamepad.java:

```
public class Gamepad extends Controller implements MotionEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onMotionEvent(MotionEvent event){
        if (event.getSource() != InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD) {

            float steering = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
            float throttle =  event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_RY);
            float brake =  event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_RX);

            if (throttle > brake) {
                message.setReverse(false);
                message.setThrottle(throttle);
            } else if (throttle < brake) {
                message.setReverse(true);
                message.setThrottle(brake);
            } else {
                message.setReverse(false);
                message.setThrottle(0.0f);
            }

            message.setSteering(steering);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public ControllerMessage getControllerMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    @Override
    public float getMinThrottle() {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public float getMaxThrottle() {
        return 1.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public float getMinSteering() {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public float getMaxSteering() {
        return 1.0f;
    }
}
```

MotionEventListener.java:

```
public interface MotionEventListener {
    void onMotionEvent(MotionEvent event);
}
```

Comment: могу сделать так `controller.message` - в каком коде/классе?

Comment: @Igor, конкретно в MainActivity, в методе onCreate(). В Main'е, короче

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместите `Controller` в отдельный `package`.

[Protected keyword in Java with examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/protected-keyword-in-java-with-examples/#:%7E:text=Protected%20keyword%20in%20Java%20refers,Subclasses%20of%20same%20packages.)